# Sanitizing innerHTML while still executing innerHTML change?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm creating an alert plugin (pure JavaScript, no jQuery) that will allow users to input custom HTML into their alert boxes. However, XSS attacks and DOM attacks are a major concern because I use .innerHTML to achieve this. My attempt at input sanitation is below. The problem is that the HTML tags are included in the output. Is there a way to prevent against these attacks while still performing the requested innerHTML change and have no tags showing in the output?

```
 <!--Example-->

 //HTML
 <div id='div'></div>

 //JavaScript
 var name = '<h1>james</h1>';

 function sanitizeHTML(unsafeString) { 
  return unsafeString.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
  .replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
  .replace(/\'/g, '&#39;')
  .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;');
};

document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = sanitizeHTML(name);

//Outputs '<h1>james</h1>' with tags showing
```

Comment: so, you want to remove the tags but keep the text?

Comment: I want to keep the text, but make that text into an h1 element and make sure the input is secure

Comment: so you allow HTML, but want to ensure it's *safe* HTML only?

Comment: correct. I want to user to be able to add things like <ul> and <div> to the alert, but I want to stop someone from throwing in a script tag for instance and running malicious code

Comment: Then sanitize based on a whilelist of allowed input tags, instead of what you're doing now. Since this is an alert, `<h1>` shouldn't really be allowed, since you should only have one `<h1>` on a page.